# Korrekter Gebrauch von Abkürzungen

Tags: reference, scientific-language

In einem wissentschaftlichen Text möchte ich zum Referenzieren verschiedene Abkürzungen verwenden. Bei den zu referenzierenden Textbausteinen handelt es sich um `Anwendungsfälle`, `Anforderungen`, `Funktionen`, `Forschungsfragen` und `allgemeine Ziele`.

Derzeit schreibe ich z. B. `ANW 5`, für den Anwendungsfall fünf. Der Anwendungsfall wird dafür zunächst beschrieben und anschließend mit Namen im Text hervorgehoben. Auf diese Stelle im Text referenziere ich dann später mehrmals.

- Zunächst, sollte ich zum Referenzieren überhaupt Abkürzungen verwenden?
- Sollte ich das Wort Anwendungsfall nun immer abkürzen oder nur beim Referenzieren? (letzteres mache ich derzeit)

Falls ja, wie sollte eine Abkürzung aussehen? Betrachten wir das Beispiel `Anwendungsfall`:

- Welche Buchstaben sollte ich verwenden? `Anw`, `Anf`, `UC` für englisch `Use case`
- Sollten die Buchstaben alle groß oder nur der erste groß geschrieben werden?
- Sollte hinter einer Abkürzung ein Punk stehen?
- Wie verfahre ich im Plural, also z. B. um auf mehrere Anwendungsfälle zu referenzieren?

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, was du mit "Referenzieren" meinst. Ich habe das Gefühl, wenn du etwas mehr erläuterst, was du da machst und was das für Textbausteine sind, wird die Frage klarer.

Comment: Generell werden zum Abkürzen die Buchstaben verwendet, die im Abgekürzten verwendet werden, also etwa BaföG, GmbH, z.B. usw. Punkte sind wohl nur bei verzichtbar, wenn die Abkürzung auch so abekürzt gesprochen wird, SPD etwa ja, usw. jedoch nicht.

Comment: Es sieht so aus, als wenn Du eine Methode für eine Strukturierte Requirements Analyse (Software Methodologie) benötigst. Hier ist ein guter Ausgangspunkt mit Templates (Textbausteinen) und Vorgehensweisen: http://arc42.org/

Comment: Nach weniger als 10 Sekunden googeln gefunden: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/abkuerzungen Auch hilfreich: http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Abkuerzung.html Sogar in Wikipedia kann man einiges erfahren: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkürzung

Comment: Ich habe einmal gelesen, dass man in Zeiten moderner Textverarbeitungssysteme auf solche Abkürzungen in solchen Texten verzichten soll. Die Abkürzungen erleichtern vielleicht das Schreiben, hemmen den Lesefluss aber deutlich. Die Empfehlung jenes Textes war, stattdessen die Textbausteine des Textverarbeitungssystems zu nutzen. So kann der Schreiber mit Abkürzungen arbeiten, die aber vom System automatisch in die lesbare Langfassung umgesetzt werden.

Comment: Ich finde, hinter jeder Abkürzung sollte ein Punk stehen!

Comment: @Philipp  Ich fände es schöner, da stünde dann ein Emo.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn ich das richtig verstehe geht es dir nicht um Regeln für existierende Abkürzungen, sondern die Kreation von eigenen Abkürzungen. Dabei gilt zu beachten:

1. Es gibt keine festen Regeln, wie man Abkürzungen generieren muss.
2. In einigen Fachbereichen gibt es solche Regeln (siehe Links von Hubert Schölnast).
3. Im Allgemeinen würde man Abkürzungen beim ersten Auftreten des Wortes in Klammern einführen und danach verwenden.
4. Verwendet man viele Abkürzungen, so empfiehlt sich ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis (vor allem in Lexika und anderen Werken, die man nicht von vorne bis hinten durchliest).
5. Vom übermäßigen Gebrauch von Abkürzungen ist abzusehen.
6. Es empfiehlt sich, Abkürzungen aus den Anfangsbuchstaben der Silben oder der zusammengesetzten Wortteile, oder aber den ersten drei Buchstaben zu bilden.

Meine Empfehlungen für deine Beispiele:

1. Anwendungsfall: AWF, Anw. (liest man eher als "Anwendung"), ANW, AnWF
2. Anforderung: AF, Anf.
3. Forschungsfragen: FF, FFR, FoFr.
4. allgemeine Ziele: AZ, aZ, AlgZ

Im wissenschaftlichen Kontext werden für Abkürzungen meist Großbuchstaben verwendet. Im Plural steht es dir frei, ob du AWFe, AWFs oder AWF schreibst.

Zum Edit: Ich würde bei jedem Anwendungsfall schreiben

> Anwendungsfall 1 (AWF1):

Somit könntest du gut auf die einzelnen Anwendungsfälle referenzieren und trotzdem im Fließtext von "Anwendungsfällen" sprechen. Beispiel:

> Man erkennt, dass Anwendungsfälle Forschungsfragen aufwerfen. So betrachtet AWF1 die Forschungsfrage FF17.

Ich habe hier bewusst einmal "Forschungsfrage FF17" geschrieben, da das auch eine mögliche Formulierung wäre. In Mathe würde man z.B. Regeln mit R1, R2, ... durchnumerieren, im Text aber trotzdem "Regel R1" schreiben. Du siehst, es gibt viele Möglichkeiten, aber keine Regeln.

PS: Ich empfehle das Schreiben von wissenschaftlichen Texten auf Englisch.

Comment: Dein Empfehlungen sind gut für den allgemeinen Gebrauch. Ich habe aber den Verdacht, dass der Fragesteller irgend einen sehr spezifischen Anwendungsfall im Auge hatte, den er uns aber nicht verrät... siehe  Panta Reis Kommentar.

Comment: Ich denke bei so etwas automatisch an wissenschaftliche Texte. Aber wenn der Fragesteller noch weiterführende oder spezifischere Angaben macht, können wir uns dem ja annehmen :)